# Can I put a Image element in a ResourceDictionary and then reference it in DataTemplate? [UWP]

Tags: c#, xaml, uwp

I tried to reference an Image I placed in my ResourceDictionary but it caused the app to crash. I just thought it would use less system resources when place in a ResourceDictionary, since my DataTemplate is going to use that Image element for every generated item. Am I even taking the right approach here?

This is what I placed in my ResourceDictionary, and then referenced using the StaticResource markup extension. Note that it is a .svg image:

```
<Image x:Key="Archive_Rudiment"
       Source="..\Assets\Icons\Archive_Rudiment.svg"
       Width="20"
       Height="20" />
```

Comment: Did you tried using absolute Uri for Image.Source?

Comment: What exactly do you mean? Thanks for the reply.

Comment: You are using **relative** Uri as `..\Assets\Icons\Archive_Rudiment.svg`, try changing it to **absolute** Uri like `ms-appx:///Assets/Icons/Archive_Rudiment.svg` to see if it works.

Comment: I did just what you asked, then I referenced the resource like this: <Button Content="{StaticResource Archive_Rudiment}" />

It still crashed.

Comment: Never mind. Just learned that the Image type is not a shareable resource. Thanks, though.

Comment: I just found [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33878426/failed-to-assign-to-property-windows-ui-xaml-controls-contentcontrol-content), in this way you can reuse your images.